# React Router multiple optional components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app that uses React Router, and my router looks something like this:

```
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <App>
            <Route
                exact
                name="Login"
                path="/login"
                component={Login}
            />
            <Route
                exact
                name="Home"
                path="/"
                component={Home}
            >
        </App>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

So far so good. However, I want to have the App be able to render a sidebar on the left, based on path (not all Routes would render a sidebar). Ideally, the Route component (e.g. `Home`) would be able to specify its sidebar component and the App would be able to find that and render it in the appropriate place. But `App` just gets a bunch of children which are `Route` components, and as far as I can tell, there's no way to determine which route(s) have actually been rendered from within App.

Presumably, I could have separate Route components to define the sidebar components, but I would prefer to not have to duplicate Routes so that I can associate the sidebar with its component (e.g. Home would have a sidebar and it would be possible to look at the code for the Home component to see what its sidebar would look like, rather than some other completely different file).

Comment: I think I had a pretty similar problem, but in my case there were few "groups" of pages / components - where some would need to have a sidebar while others not. e.g. there was a "Products" group of pages with a sidebar and a "Login / Register" group without one. Would you be interested in that kind of solution?

Comment: That sounds like it could be what I'd be looking for, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

React router is pretty powerful in terms of combining your components together based on the url. In fact, you can use some "nested" routes and the library will take care of composing components for you.

Say we want to have the following:

1. A more or less standalone login / register page without a sidebar
2. A set of Product CRUD pages that share some common layout, including
   the `Sidebar` component

To achieve that - let's consider the following Route configuration. Note that the examples I'll be using refer to **react-router 3.0.2**

```
  <Router history={this.props.history}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>

      //NO SIDEBAR
      <Route path='login'  component={LoginForm} />

      // STUFF WITH THE SIDEBAR
      <Route path='products' component={ProductsLayout} onEnter={this.requireAuth}>
        <Route path="new"      component={ProductForm}/>
        <Route path=":id"      component={Product}/>
        <Route path=":id/edit" component={ProductForm}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Note that the urls for the sidebar pages will look something like `/products/new` and `products/123/edit` since the `path` property is inherited down by the child components.

And here is what the `ProductLayout` component would look like. Note that I'm using some of the Bootstrap components here (Row, Col) - but those can be ignored:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col }         from 'react-bootstrap';
import Sidebar              from 'components/Sidebar';

class ProductsLayout extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
          // --> THIS IS WHERE OUR SIDEBAR COMES INTO PLAY <--
          <Sidebar/>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} sm={6} md={8} lg={6} className="product well">
          {this.props.children}
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} sm={0} md={0} lg={3}>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsLayout;
```

As a result - when we go to `/login` - there's no sidebar. And when we go to any route prefixed with `/products` - there is one.

Hope that makes sense